# Community/Experience Profile User does not obey DMLOptions - triggerAutoResponseEmail = false

Tags: apex, community

When running this code as a community user to create a case the Auto-Response email rule is being triggered

```
Case myCase = new Case(
            AccountId = company.Id,
            ContactId = testCommunityContact.Id,
            OwnerId = QueueId,
            RecordTypeId = GE_CASE_RECORD_ID,
            Subject = 'Test Subject',
            Description = 'Test Description'
        );
        
Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.emailHeader.triggerAutoResponseEmail = false;

Database.insert(myCase, dmlOpts);
```

Is this expected behaviour for community users?
I cannot see any mention of this behaviour - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Database_EmailHeader.htm

I did find this current known issue - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000Fmk0QAC
But that is the opposite of what we are experiencing...

Comment: As per SF doc, if `triggerAutoResponseEmail` is set to `false`, then `the email is sent to the address specified in SuppliedEmail`. Have you checked if the `SuppliedEmail` in case object is being defaulted or updated by some other process? And, is this happening only for community users?

Comment: Correct this ONLY happens for community users
And added
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty([SELECT CaseNumber, SuppliedEmail FROM Case]));

to my test method and SuppliedEmail is blank/null

Searched the apex and flows, there is no references about that field, so definitely caused by that field populated.

Comment: While it shows up null value in system.debug statements, have you checked by querying a record that has been created?

Comment: Yep, confirmed it is null even when viewing the created record.

Comment: Could it be possible that there are other email notifications configured in the org? For testing, can you deactivate all the case auto response rules (there by making the DML Options pointless)? and, check if emails are still getting generated?

Comment: No, I can see from the debug logs that it is triggering from the auto-response rule.
And when running the code as a staff member, it does not trigger that same rule, it does not even mention looking at the auto-response rules.

Comment: Are you observing this in other orgs (Developer edition or sandboxes)? Could this be an org specific defect that only SF can fix?

Comment: It's definitely in 2 of the developer/pro edition sandboxes, as it was picked up in the QA env by the tester.

Comment: I have resorted to raising a case with Salesforce to try and get this resolved :(

Comment: Hopefully they get it resolved.